# Trying to become a better Flutter programmer

Tags: flutter, dart, domain-driven-design, clean-architecture

Could someone please tell me what the advantage is of calling a method from a Riverpod provider through a prior subscription, using a listen without a callback, like this?:

```dart
@riverpod
FutureOr<Option<User>> signInState(SignInStateRef ref) {
  final sub = ref.listen(authStateProvider.notifier, (prev, next) {});
  ref.listenSelf((previous, next) {
    next.whenData(
      (user) {
        if (user is Some<User>) {
          sub.read().authenticateUser(user.value);
        }
      },
    );
  });
```

Instead of doing it directly, as follows:

```dart
@riverpod
FutureOr<Option<User>> signInState(SignInStateRef ref) {
  ref.listenSelf((previous, next) {
    next.whenData(
      (user) {
        if (user is Some<User>) {
          ref.read(authStateProvider.notifier).authenticateUser(user.value);
        }
      },
    );
  });
```

I've seen this done in various parts of a project, but I don't understand the reason why it's a better option. I suspect there's a valuable learning opportunity behind it.

Thank you.

I tried to gather more information through debugging, but I didn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 1):

I received a response from the owner of the code. I'm sharing it with the hope that it can help those who want to excel in our profession:

> Technically, there is no difference if authStateProvider is keepAlive.
> But, it’s a good practice that you ensure the provider is listened to
> when mutating using `ref.read` (if the provider has no other listeners
> in the tree).
>
> See the following example:
>
> ```dart
> @riverpod
> class Bar extends _$Bar {
>   @override
>   int build() => 0;
>
>   void increase(int i) {
>     state = state + i;
>   }
> }
>
> @riverpod
> Future<int> Foo(FooRef ref) {
>   final sub = ref.listen(barProvider.notifier, (prev, next) {});
>
>   ref.listenSelf((previous, next) {
>     next.whenData(
>       (state) {
>         sub.read().increase(1);
>       },
>     );
>   });
> }
> ```
>
> If barProvider has no listeners in the tree and you directly used
> ref.read, the behavior will be different because barProvider will be
> called and disposed immediately with each ref.read call.

Here are my key takeaways from the response:

`With providers marked as keepAlive like authStateProvider:`

- It doesn't matter much whether you use `ref.listen` + `sub.read()` or `ref.read()` directly.
- The provider will not be unnecessarily reconstructed in any case.
- There is no significant difference in performance or optimization.

`On the other hand, with providers not marked as keepAlive:`

- If `ref.read()` is used directly, the provider is reconstructed with each call.
- Instead, with `ref.listen` + `sub.read()`, it is reconstructed only once.
- This can improve performance in providers not marked as `keepAlive`.

If you have more comments on the topic, they are welcome!

Regards.